# tomcat deploy only manager on startup

Tags: tomcat, startup, manager-app

i have a little strange problem.
The security department in my company wants every tomcat to respect the following configuration parameters:

```
autoDeploy="false"
deployOnStartup="false"
```

When i configure the above parameters no web app (including the manager-app) will be deployed on startup and i can't deploy apps through the manager-app...

Can i define the deployment of the manager-app in server.xml or something like this? I want only to deploy the manager-app on startup.

Edit:
Here is my ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml

```
...
<Service name="Catalina">
...

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
...
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false"
            deployOnStartup="false"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false"
            deployXml="false">
...
```

and this is my ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml

```
<Context path="/manager"
        docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/manager"
        debug="0"
        privileged="true"
        autoDeploy="true"
        deployOnStartup="true">

    <ResourceLink name="users"
                global="UserDatabase"
                type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
                allow="127.0.0.1"/>

</Context>
```

greets

Goetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apache 6 documentation:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html
in the Attributes section of **Context**, the documentation for the **path** attribute specifies:

> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.
>
> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute must not be set **unless** either the docBase is not located under the Host's appBase or **both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false**. If this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

The same documentation exists in Tomcat 7, so I tried the following on Tomcat 7 and I managed to deploy only the manager application.

```
<Host appBase="webapps"  autoDeploy="false"  deployOnStartup="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
        <Context docBase="manager" 
               path="/manager"  
               antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" 
               />
</Host>
```

Basically, what I did was to copy the contents of the **webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml** and paste them inside the **<Host>** element of **server.xml**, ensuring of course that the **path** and **docBase** attributes were also present, as the documentation specifies. In your case I believe it would be:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false"
            deployOnStartup="false"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false"
            deployXml="false">

<Context path="/manager"
        docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/manager"
        debug="0"
        privileged="true">

    <ResourceLink name="users"
                global="UserDatabase"
                type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
                allow="127.0.0.1"/>

</Context>

</Host>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
Meanwhile i have upgraded also to Tomcat 7 and your solutions works for me. :)

Greets Goetz

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from this  [link](https://serverfault.com/a/482987) , I think it's the solution you are looking for.

Comment: sorry, but this don't solve my problem. At the link the DeployOnStartUp as "true", but i want it to be "false".

Comment: Instead of autoDeploy="true" parameter you can use  deployOnStartup="false".

Comment: I have tried this. But it didn't work as excepted. I added to the post the corresponding config snippets.

Comment: Use   docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/" instead of   docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/manager", you have already defined manager path with path="/manager" parameter.

Comment: I tried it, but it changed nothing. :( is there a different behaviour between the files ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml and ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml?